# How can I place a table (including caption) across two columns of a \twocolum document?

Tags: tables, two-column, multicol, multicolumn

I have inserted a table in a two column document. The table should span across both columns without a page break. Ideally, the table should be fixed at the top of a page with two columns of text below. I almost got what I wanted using `\FloatBarrier`. The table now ignores the columns and spans across the whole page breadth. However, this didn't work for the caption below, which is fit into the left column. I also noticed that in Overleaf the text gets printed over the table and the table is still fixed to a column (when it gets positioned on a right side column, it stretches over the borders of the page).
Is there a way to get the result I want (see picture)[image]?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[left={2.5cm},right={2.5cm},top={2cm},bottom={2.5cm}]{geometry}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\usepackage{placeins}

\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn
\lipsum[3-5]

\FloatBarrier

\begin{table}[!tbh]

\centering

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lllll}

%\toprule
\textbf{step} & \textbf{extractant} & \textbf{target phase} & \parbox{3cm}{\bfseries possible mechanism} & \textbf{reference} \\
\addlinespace[0.2cm]
\parbox[t][][t]{\widthof{digestion}}{PO\(_4\)} & \parbox[t][][t]{\widthof{1\,M NaH2PO4}}{1\,M NaH2PO4, pH\,5, 16\,h, 24\,h + water wash} & \parbox[t][][t]{\widthof{As coprecipitated}}{adsorbed As} & \parbox[t][][t]{3.2cm}{anion exchange of PO4 for AsO4 and AsO3} & \parbox[t][][t]{3.3cm}{\cite{welchFactorsControllingShallow1998}; modified by \cite{keonValidationArsenicSequential2001}}\\

\addlinespace[0.2cm]
\parbox[t][][t]{\widthof{digestion}}{HCl} & \parbox[t][][t]{\widthof{1\,M NaH2PO4}}{1\,N HCl, 2\(*\)\,1\,h + water wash} & \parbox[t][][t]{\widthof{As coprecipitated}}{As coprecipitated with Mn oxides and amorphous Fe oxides} & \multirow{3}{3.2cm}{proton dissolution; Fe-Cl complexation} & \parbox[t][][t]{3.3cm}{\cite{huerta-diazPyritizationTraceMetals1992}; \cite{cornwellCharacterizationIronSulfide1987}; \cite{wallmannNewProcedureDetermining1993}; \cite{canfieldSulfateReductionDiagenesis1988}} \\

\addlinespace[0.2cm]
\parbox[t][][t]{\widthof{digestion}}{Microwave digestion} & \parbox[t][][t]{\widthof{1\,M NaH2PO4}}{xxx} & \parbox[t][][t]{\widthof{As coprecipitated}}{xxx} & \parbox[t][][t]{3.2cm}{xxx} & \parbox[t][][t]{3.3cm}{cite{various}} \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\caption[Single Extraction: Steps]{Single Extraction Procedure; table from \cite{keonValidationArsenicSequential2001} (modified)}

\label{extraction_steps}

\end{table}

\lipsum[6-8]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `table*` instead of `table`.

Comment: Unrelated, but for molecular formulas you might want to load the `mhchem` package and use `\ce{NaH2PO4}`... Also useing `tabularx` without any `X` type column is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace `table` by `table*` your table will span both of the two columns. In the following MWE, I have also used the `mhchem` and the `siunitx` package for chemical formulae and units. Lastly, I have removed all the `parboxes` and used `tabularx`'s `X` type columns in order to get automatic linebreaks in the cells. I have also removed the justification in the cells as this causes quite large horizontal white spaces.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left={2.5cm},right={2.5cm},top={2cm},bottom={2.5cm}]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\DeclareSIUnit\Molar{M}
\DeclareSIUnit\Normal{N}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\twocolumn

\begin{table*}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\RaggedRight}p{1.75cm}*{4}{>{\RaggedRight}X}}

\toprule
\textbf{step} & \textbf{extractant} & \textbf{target phase} & \bfseries possible \newline mechanism & \textbf{reference} \\
\midrule
\ce{PO4} & \SI{1}{\Molar} \ce{NaH2PO4}, pH\,5, \SI{16}{\hour}, \SI{24}{\hour} + water wash & adsorbed As & anion exchange of \ce{PO4} for \ce{AsO4} and \ce{AsO3} & \cite{welchFactorsControllingShallow1998}; modified by \cite{keonValidationArsenicSequential2001}\\
\addlinespace[0.2cm]
HCl & \SI{1}{\Normal} HCl, 2$\cdot$\SI{1}{\hour} + water wash & As coprecipitated with Mn oxides and amorphous Fe oxides & proton dissolution; Fe-Cl complexation & \cite{huerta-diazPyritizationTraceMetals1992}; \cite{cornwellCharacterizationIronSulfide1987}; \cite{wallmannNewProcedureDetermining1993}; \cite{canfieldSulfateReductionDiagenesis1988} \\
\addlinespace[0.2cm]
Microwave digestion & xxx & xxx & xxx & \cite{various} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\caption[Single Extraction: Steps]{Single Extraction Procedure; table from \cite{keonValidationArsenicSequential2001} (modified)}
\label{extraction_steps}
\end{table*}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Finally, a small comment about the contents of the table: There seem to be some missing charges especially regarding PO4, AsO4,...

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I wanted and it's even less complicated than what I've tried. As for the charges, that's how it was published in the original, I guess some simplification is ok here, since it isn't an equation but rather a short explanation of possible mechanisms